# Multiple Exception in one try block

Tags: php, exception

How to catch multiple messages in one try?

```
try{
    if (empty($news_genre)){
        throw new Exception('<div class="error">Error 1</div>');
    }elseif (strlen($news_title) < 30){
        throw new Exception('<div class="error">Error 2</div>');
    } elseif (strlen($news_image)< 30){
        throw new Exception('<div class="error">Error 3</div>'); 
    } elseif (strlen($news_description)< 500){
        throw new Exception('<div class="error">Error 4</div>'); 
    } elseif (count($news_tags) > 5){
        throw new Exception('<div class="error">Error 5</div>'); 
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ($e->getMessage());
}
```

I wanna echo all errors in one line something like this:

```
//die ($e->getMessage(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getMessage());    
<div class="error">Error 1</div>
<div class="error">Error 2</div>
<div class="error">Error 3</div>
<div class="error">Error 4</div>
<div class="error">Error 5</div>
```

**PS** without different catch block!

Comment: Why? It won't get past the first throwed exception

Comment: I know, it's just the wrong example.

Comment: That's not what exceptions are for. Neither is that how exceptions work

Comment: I don't think its possible the catch block only takes one argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't catch multiple exceptions because there can't *be* multiple exceptions.  Once an exception is thrown, the code block exits with the state of that exception.

If you're looking to create a list of validation errors then you shouldn't be using exceptions for that in the first place.  (Don't use exceptions for logic flow.)  You should just be checking the logic and building your list.  In pseudo-code (since my PHP is rusty enough to be nearly non-existent):

```
if (someCondition()) {
    // add error to array
}
if (anotherCondition()) {
    // add another error to array
}
// etc.

if (array has values) {
    // display validation messages
    // halt execution
}
```

(Note also that I changed your `else if` structure to multiple `if`s, since logically you can also only ever have *one* message with that `else if` structure.)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the messages in one var, and throw a exception if one of the if's statements are executed.

```
try{
    $msg = false;
    if (empty($news_genre))
        $msg .= '<div class="error">Error 1</div>';
    if (strlen($news_title) < 30)
        $msg .= '<div class="error">Error 2</div>';
    if (strlen($news_image)< 30)
        $msg .= '<div class="error">Error 3</div>'; 
    if (strlen($news_description)< 500)
        $msg .= '<div class="error">Error 4</div>'; 
    if (count($news_tags) > 5)
        $msg .= '<div class="error">Error 5</div>'; 
    if ($msg)
        throw new Exception($msg); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: @user1791020 have you tried this code ? Did you see that I changed  `elseif` to `if` ?